# How to reduce the time to solve this system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I am trying to solve the system of equations. My code

```
  {x, y, z, a, b, m, n} /. Solve[{1/x + 1/y == 1/z, a/x  + b/y == m/n, 2 <= x <= 30, 2 <= y <= 30, 1 <= z <= 30, 2 <= a <= 10, 2 <= b <= 10, a > b, 2 <= m <= 10, 2 <= n <= 10, x > y, GCD[m, n] == 1, GCD[a, b, m] == 1, m <= n}, {x, y, z, a, b, m, n}, Integers]
```

For a long time, I can not get the result. How can I reduce the time?

Comment: Try splitting the problem. `Solve[{1/x + 1/y == 1/z, 2 <= y < x <= 30, 1 <= z <= 30}, {x, y, 
  z}, Integers]` returns a reasonable number of candidates, which you can then test with your other criteria.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inspired by @Eric Towers

```
Clear["`*"];

cf = With[{eps = 10^-12.},
   Compile[{},
    Do[
     If[And[GCD[m, n] == 1, Abs[a/x + b/y - m/n] < eps], Sow@{x, y, z, a, b, m, n}],
     {x, 2, 30},
     {y, 2, x - 1},
     {z, 2, 30},
     {a, If[Abs[1/x + 1/y - 1/z] > eps, Continue[]]; 2, 10},
     {b, 2, a - 1},
     {m, 2, 10},
     {n, If[GCD[a, b, m] != 1, Continue[]]; m + 1, 10}
     ]]];

AbsoluteTiming[ans = Reap[cf[]][[2, 1]]]
Length[ans]
```

Output

> {0.0080338, {{12,4,3,3,2,3,4},{12,4,3,4,2,5,6},{12,6,4,4,3,5,6},{12,6,4,5,2,3,4},{12,6,4,6,2,5,6},{15,10,6,3,2,2,5},{15,10,6,6,2,3,5},{15,10,6,6,3,7,10},{15,10,6,6,5,9,10},{15,10,6,7,2,2,3},{15,10,6,8,3,5,6},{15,10,6,9,2,4,5},{18,9,6,4,3,5,9},{18,9,6,6,2,5,9},{18,9,6,6,3,2,3},{18,9,6,6,4,7,9},{18,9,6,6,5,8,9},{18,9,6,7,4,5,6},{18,9,6,8,3,7,9},{18,9,6,9,3,5,6},{18,9,6,10,2,7,9},{18,9,6,10,3,8,9},{20,5,4,4,2,3,5},{20,5,4,4,3,4,5},{20,5,4,6,2,7,10},{20,5,4,7,2,3,4},{20,5,4,10,2,9,10},{24,8,6,3,2,3,8},{24,8,6,6,3,5,8},{24,8,6,6,4,3,4},{24,8,6,6,5,7,8},{24,8,6,7,3,2,3},{24,8,6,8,4,5,6},{24,8,6,9,2,5,8},{24,8,6,9,4,7,8},{24,12,8,5,2,3,8},{24,12,8,6,5,2,3},{24,12,8,7,4,5,8},{24,12,8,8,5,3,4},{24,12,8,8,6,5,6},{24,12,8,9,3,5,8},{24,12,8,9,6,7,8},{24,12,8,10,3,2,3},{24,12,8,10,4,3,4},{28,21,12,4,3,2,7},{28,21,12,8,3,3,7},{30,6,5,5,3,2,3},{30,6,5,5,4,5,6},{30,6,5,6,3,7,10},{30,6,5,7,4,9,10},{30,6,5,8,2,3,5},{30,6,5,9,3,4,5},{30,6,5,10,3,5,6},{30,15,10,5,2,3,10},{30,15,10,6,3,2,5},{30,15,10,8,5,3,5},{30,15,10,9,6,7,10},{30,15,10,9,8,5,6},{30,15,10,10,4,3,5},{30,15,10,10,5,2,3},{30,15,10,10,7,4,5},{30,20,12,6,2,3,10},{30,20,12,9,2,2,5},{30,20,12,9,8,7,10}}}

> 64

Previous answer

```
Clear["`*"];

gcd = Function[{a0, b0}, 
  Module[{a = a0, b = b0, t}, While[b != 0, {a, b} = {b, Mod[a, b]}];a]];

cf = With[{gcd = gcd, eps = 10^-12.},
   Compile[{{x, _Integer}},
    Module[{bag = Internal`Bag[Most@{0}]}, 
     Do[If[And[Abs[1/x+1/y-1/z]<eps,Abs[a/x+b/y-m/n]<eps,gcd[m,n]==1,gcd[gcd[a,b],m]==1], 
       Internal`StuffBag[bag, {x, y, z, a, b, m, n}, 1]],
      {y, 2, x - 1}, {z, 2, 30}, {a, 2, 10}, {b, 2, a - 1}, {m, 2, 10}, {n, m + 1, 10}];
     Internal`BagPart[bag, All]],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C"]];

AbsoluteTiming[ans = Join @@ (Partition[#, 7] & /@ cf[Range[2, 30]])]
Length[ans]
```

Verifying

```
And @@ Function[{x,y,z,a,b,m,n}, And[a>b,x>y,n>m,1/x+1/y==1/z,a/x+b/y==m/n,
  GCD[m,n]==1,GCD[a,b,m]==1]] @@@ ans
```

> True

Comment: I want to know how you master the compiling skills, which is very complicated for me.

Comment: @chyanog ,very sophisticated solution. You got 42 solutions. With the method @J.M. proposes in his comment, you get 64 solutions verified. `(sol3 = Solve[{1/xx + 1/yy == 1/zz, 2 <= yy < xx <= 30, 1 <= zz <= 30}, {xx, yy, zz}, Integers]) // AbsoluteTiming ` .   `(sol5 = DeleteCases[Solve[{1/x + 1/y == 1/z, a/x + b/y == m/n, 2 <= a <= 10, 2 <= b <= 10, a > b, 2 <= m <= 10, 2 <= n <= 10, x > y, m <= n, GCD[m, n] == 1, GCD[a, b, m] == 1, x == xx, y == yy, z == zz} /. #, {x, y, z, a, b, m, n}, Integers] & /@ sol3, {}]) // AbsoluteTiming `

Comment: @Akku14 Thanks for pointing out, I ignored the floating point precision issue at first.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

system = And @@ {1/x + 1/y == 1/z, a/x + b/y == m/n, 2 <= x <= 30, 
    2 <= y <= 30, 1 <= z <= 30, 2 <= a <= 10, 2 <= b <= 10, a > b, 
    2 <= m <= 10, 2 <= n <= 10, x > y, GCD[m, n] == 1, GCD[a, b, m] == 1, 
    m <= n};
```

You can use [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to identify a few solutions

```
(sol = FindInstance[system, {x, y, z, a, b, m, n}, Integers, 
    2]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {307.661, {{x -> 30, y -> 15, z -> 10, a -> 9, b -> 6, m -> 7, 
   n -> 10}, {x -> 15, y -> 10, z -> 6, a -> 6, b -> 2, m -> 3, n -> 5}}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
system /. sol

(* {True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually have that many cases:

- $x$ and $y$: $\frac{1}{2} 30 \cdot 30 = 450$.
- $z$: $30$.
- $a$ and $b$: $\frac{1}{2} 9 \cdot 9 \approx 40$.
- $m$ and $n$: $\frac{1}{2} 9 \cdot 9 \approx 40$.

So $450 \cdot 30 \cdot 40 \cdot 40 = 21.6 \times 10^6$ cases.  And this doesn't discard cases that can be early rejected, for instance, rejecting those $z$ not satisfying $1/x + 1/y = 1/z$.  Generating the cases directly and discarding early, we get something like

```
compute := Reap[
  For[x = 2, x <= 30, x++,
    For[y = 2, y < x, y++,
      For[z = 1, z <= 30, z++,
        If[1/x + 1/y == 1/z,
          For[a = 2, a <= 10, a++,
            For[b = 2, b < a, b++,
              For[m = 2, m <= 10, m++,
                If[GCD[a, b, m] == 1,
                  For[n = m, n <= 10, n++,
                    If[And[a/x + b/y == m/n, GCD[m, n] == 1],
                      Sow[{x, y, z, a, b, m, n}];
                    ];
                  ]
                ];
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ];
      ]
    ]
  ];
  Clear[x, y, z, a, b, m, n];
][[2, 1]]
```

Then,

```
RepeatedTiming[
  compute
]
(*  {0.130, {
  {12, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4}, {12, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6}, 
  {12, 6, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6}, {12, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4}, 
  {12, 6, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6}, {15, 10, 6, 3, 2, 2, 5}, 
  {15, 10, 6, 6, 2, 3, 5}, {15, 10, 6, 6, 3, 7, 10}, 
  {15, 10, 6, 6, 5, 9, 10}, {15, 10, 6, 7, 2, 2, 3}, 
  {15, 10, 6, 8, 3, 5, 6}, {15, 10, 6, 9, 2, 4, 5}, 
  {18, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 9}, {18, 9, 6, 6, 2, 5, 9}, 
  {18, 9, 6, 6, 3, 2, 3}, {18, 9, 6, 6, 4, 7, 9}, 
  {18, 9, 6, 6, 5, 8, 9}, {18, 9, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6}, 
  {18, 9, 6, 8, 3, 7, 9}, {18, 9, 6, 9, 3, 5, 6}, 
  {18, 9, 6, 10, 2, 7, 9}, {18, 9, 6, 10, 3, 8, 9}, 
  {20, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5}, {20, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5}, 
  {20, 5, 4, 6, 2, 7, 10}, {20, 5, 4, 7, 2, 3, 4}, 
  {20, 5, 4, 10, 2, 9, 10}, {24, 8, 6, 3, 2, 3, 8}, 
  {24, 8, 6, 6, 3, 5, 8}, {24, 8, 6, 6, 4, 3, 4}, 
  {24, 8, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8}, {24, 8, 6, 7, 3, 2, 3}, 
  {24, 8, 6, 8, 4, 5, 6}, {24, 8, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8}, 
  {24, 8, 6, 9, 4, 7, 8}, {24, 12, 8, 5, 2, 3, 8}, 
  {24, 12, 8, 6, 5, 2, 3}, {24, 12, 8, 7, 4, 5, 8}, 
  {24, 12, 8, 8, 5, 3, 4}, {24, 12, 8, 8, 6, 5, 6}, 
  {24, 12, 8, 9, 3, 5, 8}, {24, 12, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8}, 
  {24, 12, 8, 10, 3, 2, 3}, {24, 12, 8, 10, 4, 3, 4}, 
  {28, 21, 12, 4, 3, 2, 7}, {28, 21, 12, 8, 3, 3, 7}, 
  {30, 6, 5, 5, 3, 2, 3}, {30, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6}, 
  {30, 6, 5, 6, 3, 7, 10}, {30, 6, 5, 7, 4, 9, 10}, 
  {30, 6, 5, 8, 2, 3, 5}, {30, 6, 5, 9, 3, 4, 5}, 
  {30, 6, 5, 10, 3, 5, 6}, {30, 15, 10, 5, 2, 3, 10}, 
  {30, 15, 10, 6, 3, 2, 5}, {30, 15, 10, 8, 5, 3, 5}, 
  {30, 15, 10, 9, 6, 7, 10}, {30, 15, 10, 9, 8, 5, 6}, 
  {30, 15, 10, 10, 4, 3, 5}, {30, 15, 10, 10, 5, 2, 3}, 
  {30, 15, 10, 10, 7, 4, 5}, {30, 20, 12, 6, 2, 3, 10}, 
  {30, 20, 12, 9, 2, 2, 5}, {30, 20, 12, 9, 8, 7, 10}
  }}  *)
```

IF we're curious how many cases are actually fully generated (so actually accounting for the early rejections), we can add a counter and modify the inner `For` loop.

```
count = 0;
Reap[
  For[x = 2, x <= 30, x++,
    ...
                  For[n = m, n <= 10, n++,
                    count++;
                    If[And[a/x + b/y == m/n, GCD[m, n] == 1],
                      Sow[{x, y, z, a, b, m, n}];
                    ];
                  ]
    ...
  ];
  Clear[x, y, z, a, b, m, n];
][[2, 1]];
count

(* 15816 *)
```

So *several* cases are rejected by the `If`s.

Alternatively, we can stage `Solve`s similar to the structure above: first generate all possible `x,y,z` triples, then try to solve for `a,b,m,n`s for each of those.

```
Clear[x, y, z, a, b, m, n];
extend[xyz_] := ({x, y, z, a, b, m, n} /. 
  Join[xyz, #]) & /@ 
    Solve[{a/x + b/y == m/n, 2 <= a <= 10, 2 <= b <= 10, a > b, 
      2 <= m <= 10, 2 <= n <= 10, GCD[m, n] == 1, GCD[a, b, m] == 1, 
      m <= n} /. xyz, {a, b, m, n}, Integers]

Join @@ (extend /@ 
  Solve[{1/x + 1/y == 1/z, 2 <= x <= 30, 2 <= y <= 30, 1 <= z <= 30, 
    x > y}, {x, y, z}, Integers])
```

`extend` is a function taking a triple of the form, for instance, `{x -> 6, y -> 3, z -> 2}`, one element of the list output by the `Solve` over `{x,y,z}`.  It uses this to find `a, b, m, n` that satisfy the rest of the constraints.  It's slower than the `For` loops,

```
RepeatedTiming[
  Join @@ (extend /@ 
    Solve[{1/x + 1/y == 1/z, 2 <= x <= 30, 2 <= y <= 30, 1 <= z <= 30,
     x > y}, {x, y, z}, Integers])]

(* {1.153, { ... }}  *)
```

but faster than "a long time".

Comment: The last solution is more or less what I had in mind in my comment. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

If you want speed for larger upper bounds on the variables $\{x,y,z,a,b,m,n\}$, then the following is much faster than even the compiled solution by @chyanog (+1).

Rewrite the original equation $1/x+1/y-1/z=0$ as $(x-z)(y-z)=z^2$, after forming a common denominator $x y z>0$, and multiplying through by it. If $r*s$ is a factorization of a given $z^2$ on the right-hand side, then the solutions are $\{x,y\}=\{r,s\}+z$. This is from making a correspondence between the two factors on the left-hand side of the equation and those of $r*s$ on the right.

Generate divisor pairs $r*s=z^2$ with the larger one first.

```
DivisorPairs[n_] := Thread[{Reverse[#], #}][[ ;; Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]] &[Divisors[n]]
```

Run through the range of $z$, generating solution triples $\{x,y,z\}$. Note, the maximum $z$ is only half the maximum of $x$ or $y$.

```
xyzSolve[max_] :=
   Block[{xyz},
      Flatten[Table[
         Pick[#, UnitStep[max - #[[All, 1]]], 1] &[
            Map[Join[#, {z}] &, z + Most[DivisorPairs[z^2]]]],
      {z, 2, max/2 - 1}], 1]]
```

For example, there are 12 solutions to $1/x+1/y=1/z$, $x>y$, $2\le x\le 30$, $2\le y\le 30$, $1\le z\le 30$.

```
xyzSolve[30]
```

> {{6, 3, 2}, {12, 4, 3}, {20, 5, 4}, {12, 6, 4}, {30, 6, 5}, {24, 8, 6}, {18, 9, 6},
> {15, 10, 6}, {24, 12, 8}, {30, 15, 10}, {30, 20,
> 12}, {28, 21, 12}}

For any solution $\{x,y\}$ of $1/x+1/y=1/z$, and given $\{m,n\}$, the second equation $a/x+b/y=m/n$ becomes a simple linear Diophantine equation $a (n y)+b (n x)=m x y$ for the unknowns $\{a,b\}$. Allow for $b_{min}\le b < a\le a_{max}$, and solve via an extended GCD.

```
abSolve[u_Integer, v_Integer, n_Integer, bmin_, amax_] :=
   Block[{g, r, s, k, ab},
      {g, {r, s}} = ExtendedGCD[u, v];
      ab = Table[{r*n + v*k, s*n - u*k}/g, {k, Ceiling[-r*n/v], Quotient[s*n, u]}];
      Select[Pick[ab, Denominator[ab[[All, 1]]], 1], amax >= #[[1]] > #[[2]] >= bmin &]
]
```

Given $n$, use the following `RelativePrimes[n]` to find allowed $m\le n$.

```
RelativePrimes[n_Integer] := Pick[#, GCD[n, #], 1] &[Range[n]]
```

Given a solution $\{x,y,z\}$, find corresponding values $\{a,b,m,n\}$, assuming $n\ge 2$ and $m\ge 2$.

```
getSolution[{x_, y_, z_}, bmin_, amax_, nmax_] :=
   Pick[#, GCD @@@ (#[[All, {4, 5, 6}]]), 1] &[Flatten[Table[
      Map[Join[{x, y, z}, #, {m, n}] &, abSolve[n y, n x, m x y, bmin, amax]],
      {n, 2, nmax}, {m, Rest[RelativePrimes[n]]}], 2]]
```

Solve the original problem in about 0.01 s.

```
RepeatedTiming[
   Length[Flatten[Map[getSolution[#, 2, 10, 10] &, xyzSolve[30]], 1]]
]
```

> {0.0094, 64}

If the upper limit is increased to 100 from 30, then this code takes about 6.5 seconds to find the 19841 valid solutions. The compiled solution takes about 85 times longer.

```
RepeatedTiming[
   Length[Flatten[Map[getSolution[#, 2, 100, 100] &, xyzSolve[100]], 1]]
]
```

> {6.32, 19841}